# Keep secret data after app removed?

Tags: android, keystore

I try to use the KeyStore to save some secret. but after removed the app from android device, the keypair also removed from the device.

Is there any way I can save keypair ever app removed. The reason I still want the keypair is: if user re-install the app, the keypair still exist and keep the same.

Comment: that is not good to store user information if the app is unistalled from the device.

Comment: it would be better to store such info somewhere off user device, server for example.

Comment: @Aj 27  iOS guy told me, iOS's keystore has such feature, it can keep the key even after user remove the app. I hope android also has such feature.

By the way, my app is server-less app.

Comment: @DavidGuo, I think you are creating a crypto wallet if I am not wrong? :)

Answer (score 3):

You could store credentials in Android KeyChain when you want system-wide credentials. Your keys will remain in the KeyChain even if you uninstall the application. See [KeyChain](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html) and [Choosing Between a Keychain or the Android Keystore Provider](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#WhichShouldIUse)

> The `KeyChain` class provides access to private keys and their corresponding certificate chains in credential storage.
>
> ...
>
> An application can request the installation of private keys and certificates via the Intent provided by `createInstallIntent()`. Private keys installed via this Intent will be accessible via `choosePrivateKeyAlias(Activity, KeyChainAliasCallback, String[], Principal[], Uri, String)` while Certificate Authority (CA) certificates will be trusted by all applications through the default `X509TrustManager`.

An alternative is to store the keypair in a local file and encrypt it with a password that is requested from the user.

You could also store it in this way on server, but always encrypted, so that the server does not have access to the user's keys